# Need help to create store procedure For my MYSQl query

Tags: mysql

I want to create dyanmic store procedure for this query. and how to pass multile value in brand during call procedure.I want pass multiple brand  when i call procedure .Please help.

```
select product_name,status,brand from spec_abc where
status='1' and brand in ('apple','samsung','oppo','LG')
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but why ?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
   select product_name,status,brand from spec_abc where
   status='1' and brand in ('apple','samsung','oppo','LG')
   limit 10;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Takes 10sec to watch the doc :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: thank you sir ,but how to create dynamic procedure .how to pass multiple brand during call procedure.

Comment: Where do you get your brand ? If it's from a table, you can use a [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html). Maybe even give the table as a parameter (even if I never tried myself)